# Install a Teamviewer host silently with custom password

Tags: script, batch-file, teamviewer

Our company has the custom Teamviewer hosts that we can run silently with the /S switch. The issue is that we can't connect due to it not setting a password that we know. Does anyone have any thoughts or scripts they can direct me to that will do a Teamviewer silent install and set the password with no user interaction?

Comment: You can make a package with a embedded password. Its on the Teamviewer site.

Comment: I know you could in TV8 but on the website I could not find it in the customizations for 9 or 10 host.

Comment: No longer can with 9 and upwards. You need to set the password manually, and then export the reg keys, and import on the PC's in order to set the code.

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom password file:

1. Open an existing installation of TeamViewer on any machine (this file will be machine agnostic, so it can be created from your – or any – Windows device)
2. Open Extras > Options
3. Open Advanced > Show advanced options
4. Select  “Export options to a *.reg file”
5. Give your password file a unique name

Once created, you then need to go on to the PC you wish to import the password file on, and do the following:

1. Open Extras > Options
2. Open Advanced > Show advanced options
3. Select "Import options from a *.reg file"
4. Find the file you exported from the first computer.

Comment: would that work for example also via powershell script?

Comment: You certainly could do this with powershell. After exporting the reg, you could do `reg import settings.reg`

Comment: sorry for beeing not clear enough, I know how to import a *.reg file via powershell, what I wanted to know was, if this exported password will also be "imported" by teamviewer, since the exported password will be imported into a "temporary" key and there is a distinctive "import reg" option in teamviewer?

Comment: Yes there is. http://prntscr.com/nuthr4. Although you don't need to import with TeamViewer for it to work. We deploy this out to our client's machines using a silent install script for the TeamViewer Host, and then just import a reg file.

Comment: thx! I wasn't sure TV would use the PW if we would just import the *.reg file (can't test it atm)

Answer (score -3):

You would have to go into the setting on the Hosts and set the password(s) that you would like to use.

Comment: The OP wants to set the password silently without user interaction.